# Carriage Return in password?

Tags: html, input, passwords, password-protection, carriage-return

Since a complex password is now required in most sites. Can't we use Carriage Return in password?

A password something like:

```
"MyPa$$w0rdHa$Carr1ageR3tuRn!
Here..."
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with different GUIs (browser, mobile, desktop) and platform differences (NL,CR/NL,CR) is probably not worth the additional character(s) in the search space and can lead to unsuccessful logins.

But you certainly *can* accept CarriageReturns in a user password, I just wouldn't do any extra work for them.